# Confusion matrix measure

Tags: classification, confusion-matrix

I have two confusion matrices:

(1)

```
110  -45  -45  -44  -45
-46   91  -46  -46  -46
-87  -86   98  -87  -87
-118 -118 -118  118 -118
-79  -79  -79  -79   91
```

with accuracy 36.6 and

(2)

```
99   99   98  100   99
95   95   96   95   96
95   95   95   95   94
104  105  106  105  105
89   91   91   91   91
```

with accuracy 31.7

Confusion matrix (1) is more useful than (2), because it shows the the classifier can be used to classify more accurately

Since the accuracies are very similar, what other measure can I use to show that the classifier that produced matrix (2) is basically useless?

Comment: What do the minus signs mean in the first one?

Comment: As Firebug mentioned, confusion matrix should not have negative numbers.